# perdida de pixeles! al rotar

Tags: c++

tengo una Función Rectangle(); y he implementado la rotación por centro,
el único problema es al rotar pierde pixeles, en un Sprite es peor,
se ven agujeros :(...

```
bool RECTANGLE(int X, int Y, int w, int h, int ANG){

int xt;
int yt;
int X_=0;
int Y_=0;
double theta;

for (int i = 0; i <= w; ++i)
{
    for (int o = 0; o <= h; ++o)
    {
        X_ = i; // coordenada x para cos();
        Y_ = o; // coordenada y para sin();

        theta = ANG * (pi / 180); // conversión de radianes.

        xt = X_ * cos(theta) - Y_ * sin(theta)+X;
        yt = X_ * sin(theta) + Y_ * cos(theta)+Y;

        gotoxy(xt, yt); // Pintando pixel.

    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: ¿ Que significa `al rotar pierde pixeles` ? `gotoxy( )` trabaja con enteros, así que es normal que multiples llamadas *dibujen* en el mismo sitio. Y te recomiendo **encarecidamente** que uses nombres descriptivos en tus variables, o, al menos, expliques que misión tiene cada una. Un saludo.

Comment: que al rotar se ven agujeros. pero hay manera de solucionar esto.

Comment: es de consola, hay una manera de solucionar este error al rotar? hay agujeros dentro del rectángulo al rotar.